# Automatically Save Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

Can I use visual basic, a macro, or simply change some setting to save an excel file automatically whenever changes are made? Alternatively, can an external visual basic script save an open excel file without user input (by just being run)?

The context of this problem is that I have one type of program that opens excel and enters data into a new workbook, new worksheet, or appends the data to a previous workbook file, but does not save the file. Currently the excel file must be saved by the user. A second program, which needs the data, can only import the data from a saved excel file. What I need is for that data to somehow get sent from the first program to the second, without user input/automatically. If it helps, the second program can also execute a visual basic scripts.

Are solutions to this problem possible? Let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save worksheets and workbook with .saveAs method ex:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
```

Good reource:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: you can also use woorkbook.save   
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585(v=office.15).aspx